# Problem with 'apache_getenv' since upgrading to PHP 8

Tags: php, apache, php-8

I’m hoping to get some help with an Apache/PHP 8 issue I’m encountering. Since upgrading to PHP 8 on my LAMP server, my logs have been outputting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_getenv() ...
```

I've done a quick debug with `var_dump(is_callable('apache_getenv'))` and the value returns as `bool(false)`.

I've attempted:

- Disabling PHP 8, restarting Apache, re-enabling PHP 8, and restarting Apache again
- Restarting my whole Linux system, system (for the heck of it)

Nothing seems to work and I'm a bit stumped on how to fix this. My application depends on a few environmental variables set in my site `.conf` file, so `apache_getenv` is important.

Is this just the case of a missing module or a bad install? What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

For reference, my system is running Ubuntu 18.04.5

Thanks!

Comment: How is PHP etc installed? Linux Distro, Version, Repos etc.

Comment: Have you tried use getenv()?

Comment: @madflow I'd installed PHP using `apt install php8.0 libapache2-mod-php8.0` (including the obligatory `php8.0-fpm`) on Ubuntu 18.04.5

@C.Celora Wow! I don't know why I hadn't thought to check `getenv()`. That did the trick for surfacing the ENV values I need. Thank you!

Comment: Please check your **Server API** in `phpinfo()` . Is it **Apache 2.0 Handler** ?

Comment: @Rain Yup, the SAPI is using `apache2handler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Based on @C. Celora's recommendation above, `getenv()` seemed to solve my overarching problem of not being able to get my environmental variables via `apache_getenv()`. Thank you!

I still haven't figured out why `apache_getenv` doesn't work on my PHP 8 install, but that's no longer a blocker for me.